# Відповідний переклад слова link?

Tags: переклад, from-english, вибір-слова, терміни

Який є найбільш академичний переклад слова [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink) тобто URL на будь-який ресурс в мережі Інтернет? Зустрічав і **зсилка**, і **спосилка**, і **посилання**, і незрозуміло що з цього є скажений суржик, а що дозволений варіант.
На [r2u.org.ua](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on), який я полюбляю, найсвіжіший словник який містить хоча б одне із запропонованих слів, датується 1930-м роком. Тому звісно "зсилки" в контексті Інтернету там немає.

Comment: Два найрозповсюдженіші варіянти є кальками: «посилання» – це калька з російского «ссылка» (як у книзі), «ланка» – це калька безпосередньо з англійського «link» (одне з кілець ланцюга).

Comment: Є ще _лінка_, що теж є кальною з _link_

Answer (score 9):

По-перше, мені здається, варто відзначити, що є три різні поняття:

1. Сама адреса, що ідентифікує якийсь ресурс. Це англійською найточніше називається **web-address** (також є гіпоніми *IRI*, *URI* і *URL*). Наприклад, `http://www.example.com/directory/file?query=string#fragment`.
2. Елемент користувацького інтерфейсу, натискання на який призводить до переходу на певну адресу. Англійською найточніше називається **hyper-link** (або просто *link*). Наприклад, [оцей](http://www.example.com/directory/file?query=string#fragment) і [цей](http://www.example.com/directory/file?query=string#fragment) hyper-link'и — обидва переходять на одну й ту саму адресу (тобто між hyper-link'ами і web-address'ами немає відповідності 1-до-1: декілька hyper-link'ів можуть вказувати на один web-address, а один hyper-link може змінювати місце призначення і в різні моменти часу вказувати на різні web-address'и).
3. Абстрактне посилання на якийсь ресурс (твір, веб-сторінку тощо), незалежно від способу. Наприклад:

   - цитування його тексту (оскільки я погоджуюся зі словами поета «і на оновленій землі врага не буде, супостата», то…);
   - hyper-link (пройшовши [сюди](http://www.example.com/directory/file?query=string#fragment), ви побачите…);
   - зазначення web-address'и в текстовій формі (пройшовши сюди — http://www.example.com/directory/file?query=string#fragment, — ви побачите…);
   - словесний опис (наберіть в гуглі «…», натисніть «I'm feeling lucky», натисніть третю кнопку зліва під зеленим меню…);
   - тощо.

   Все це, незалежно від місця призначення і способу, англійською називається **reference**.

«Reference» українською зазвичай передають як «[посилання](http://sum.in.ua/s/posylannja)». Це стосується майже всього спектру значення слів «to refer»/«reference»: в фільмі режисер може посилатися на інший фільм, в своїх роздумах я можу посилатися на Шопенгауера, веб-сайт може посилатися на інший веб-сайт і т.д. Це може бути пряме (безпосереднє) посилання або завуальоване (чи явно приховане) посилання.

«Web-address» українською зазвичай передають як «[веб-адреса](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=196537&page=264)» або «[інтернет-адреса](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=196537&page=264)» (або просто «[адреса](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=519&page=22)»).

«Hyper-link»:

- Перш за все, слід сказати, що коли кажуть «я дам тобі лінк», насправді часто мають на увазі веб-адресу. В такому випадку, на мою думку, і слід казати «веб-адреса». (А не застосовувати слово, що має дещо інше значення.)
- Конкретно «hyper-link», як на мене, не має єдиного перекладу. Часто застосовують «посилання» — що є насправді гіперонімом (словом з ширшим значенням). Тобто казати «посилання» в такому випадку цілком правильно, але не зовсім точно.
- Щодо спроб точно перекласти «hyper-link»:

  - [гіперпосилання](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=192759&page=632) — як на мене, не найкращий переклад через значення «гіпер-» («[вказує на перевищення норми](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=167980&page=630)») і велику довжину, але присутнє в словниках;
  - спроби кальок і словотворів: «ланка», «посиланка», «поклик», «клацка», «посилка» тощо (див. [тут](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/link)).

Comment: Дякую. В моєму питанні мался на увазі другий варіант, але я думаю шо **здебільшого** люди не поділяють перший і другий варіант, коли кажуть: "тримай цікавий лінк, там стаття така-то така-то". Вони передають технично кажучи hyperlink, але на самої справі web-address на шось. Ваш поділ дуже теоретичний. Вийнятком є, може, лише техничні тексти.

Comment: @Suncatcher, от, по-моєму, це дуже неправильно — не поділяти. Гіперлінк — це щось типу кнопки; ми ж не кажемо «я надішлю тобі кнопку» замість «я надішлю тобі адресу»; то навіщо кажемо «я надішлю тобі лінк»? Але, звісно, можу бути і неправий.

Comment: Я не кажу про теоретичні тонкощі і не кажу шо це правильно - не поділяти, а кажу про real life :) Ні разу не чув, шоб хтось казав "я надішлю тобі веб-адресу". Це довго, нудно і відірвано від жіття.

Comment: URL ще кажуть, якщо в першому сенсі, але його не транслітерірують, а пишуть як є.

Comment: Якщо link це URL, доречно було б вживати українське слово, яке відповідає суті. Колись натрапив  на варіант СТЕЖКА (джерела не можу знайти, сайт типу http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/link)

Comment: @VitaliyPro, «URL», «URI» та «IRI» — це все часткові випадки поняття «web-address». Не бачу сенсу перекладати ці часткові випадки, оскільки різниця між «URL», «URI», «IRI» та «web-address» дуже тонка і незрозуміла неспеціалісту. Я б обмежився перекладом лише загального «web-address» (а не специфічних «URL», «URI», «IRI»).

Comment: @Sasha Зазвичай, у спільноті, використовують слово "посилання" як переклад слова `link`.  Навіть не знав, що воно вважається калькою. Проте, я вважаю, що іншого варіанта перекладу цього слова в даному контексті немає на сьогодні.

Comment: @improbable, я не певен, що _посилання_ — калька. Та й навіть якщо вважати його калькою, калькування — це всього-навсього один із способів творення нових слів (зловживати ним не варто, але й відмовлятися від нього — тим паче). У слова _посилання_, по-моєму, лише один недолік — його значення доволі широке (це радше _reference_, аніж _link_), але принаймні воно охоплює й потрібні конотації.